# Undefined constructor in inherited templated singleton class c++

Tags: c++, inheritance, singleton

I ran into a problem today, using a tool I have made some times ago : a Singleton templated class.

```
template <class C>
class Singleton {
    /*! \class Singleton
    * \brief Singleton Template
    */
public:
    /*!
    * \brief Public access interface
    * \return Singleton instance
    */
    static C *getInstance (){
        // Create new instance if not initialised
        if (_singleton == NULL){
            _singleton = new C;
        }
        return (static_cast<C*> (_singleton));
    }

    /*!
    * \brief Public access destructor
    */
    static void kill(){
        // Clean Singleton object and free memory
        if (_singleton != NULL){
            delete _singleton;
            _singleton = NULL;
        }
    }
protected:
    /*!
     * \brief Empty constructor
     */
    Singleton() = default;
    /*!
     * \brief Destructor
     */
    virtual ~Singleton() = default;

private:
    static C *_singleton; /*!< Unique instance */
};

template <class C>
C *Singleton<C>::_singleton = NULL;
```

The problem arise when i try to call TextureManager::getInstance() on the (very basic) inherited class which is the following :

```
class TextureManager : public Singleton<TextureManager> {
    friend class Singleton<TextureManager>;
    /*! \class TextureManager
    * \brief Textures Container
    */
public:
protected:
    /*!
     * \brief Empty constructor
     */
    TextureManager();
    /*!
     * \brief Destructor
     */
    ~TextureManager() override;
private:
};
```

During compilation, the linker shows me an error that i understand but I do not really understand the reason :

```
build/main.o: In function `Singleton<TextureManager>::getInstance()':
main.cpp (.text._ZN9SingletonI14TextureManagerE11getInstanceEv[_ZN9SingletonI14TextureManagerE11getInstanceEv]+0x24): undefined reference to `TextureManager::TextureManager()'
```

It seems that it can't find the definition of the constructor which is in TextureManager.cpp

```
TextureManager::TextureManager() = default;
TextureManager::~TextureManager() = default;
```

This code worked on an older project I compiled using premake so my guess is that my current makefile is rubbish but i can't find why...

```
INCLUDE = -I/usr/X11R6/include/
LIBDIR  = -L/usr/X11R6/lib

SRCDIR := sources
BUILDDIR := build
TARGET := bin/game

SRCEXT := cpp
SOURCES := $(shell find $(SRCDIR) -type f -name *.$(SRCEXT))
OBJECTS := $(patsubst $(SRCDIR)/%,$(BUILDDIR)/%,$(SOURCES:.$(SRCEXT)=.o))

FLAGS = -std=c++11 -Wall
CC = g++
CFLAGS = $(FLAGS) $(INCLUDE)
LIBS =  -lglut -lGL -lGLU -lGLEW -lm

$(TARGET): $(OBJECTS)
    @echo "Linking..."
    @echo "$(CC) $(CFLAGS) $^ -o $@ $(LIBDIR) $< $(LIBS)"; $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $(LIBDIR) $< $(LIBS)

$(BUILDDIR)/%.o: $(SRCDIR)/%.$(SRCEXT)
    @mkdir -p $(@D)
    @echo "$(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $(LIBDIR) $< $(LIBS)"; $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c -o $@ $(LIBDIR) $< $(LIBS)

clean:
    @echo "Cleaning..."
    @echo "$(RM) -r $(BUILDDIR) $(TARGET)"; $(RM) -r $(BUILDDIR) $(TARGET)

.PHONY: clean
```

Now stuck for hours,
all my hopes are on you :p

Edit : full make output

```
g++ -std=c++11 -Wall -I/usr/X11R6/include/ -o build/main.o -L/usr/X11R6/lib sources/main.cpp -lglut -lGL -lGLU -lGLEW -lm
g++ -std=c++11 -Wall -I/usr/X11R6/include/ -o build/Tools/ThreadManager.o -L/usr/X11R6/lib sources/Tools/ThreadManager.cpp -lglut -lGL -lGLU -lGLEW -lm
g++ -std=c++11 -Wall -I/usr/X11R6/include/ -o build/Graphics/GraphicalEngine.o -L/usr/X11R6/lib sources/Graphics/GraphicalEngine.cpp -lglut -lGL -lGLU -lGLEW -lm
g++ -std=c++11 -Wall -I/usr/X11R6/include/ -o build/Graphics/TextureManager.o -L/usr/X11R6/lib sources/Graphics/TextureManager.cpp -lglut -lGL -lGLU -lGLEW -lm
Linking...
g++ -std=c++11 -Wall -I/usr/X11R6/include/ build/main.o build/Tools/ThreadManager.o build/Graphics/GraphicalEngine.o build/Graphics/TextureManager.o -o bin/game -L/usr/X11R6/lib build/main.o -lglut -lGL -lGLU -lGLEW -lm
build/main.o: In function `Singleton<TextureManager>::getInstance()':
main.cpp:(.text._ZN9SingletonI14TextureManagerE11getInstanceEv[_ZN9SingletonI14TextureManagerE11getInstanceEv]+0x24): undefined reference to `TextureManager::TextureManager()'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
makefile:18: recipe for target 'bin/game' failed
make: *** [bin/game] Error 1
```

Comment: Add the output of `make` to your question, and you'll see if something is missing.

Comment: If you want to use singleton, use Meyers' one:

Comment: A good advice for singleton implementation, it is a 5 min excellent Cppcon 2016 presentation [*On using singleton in C++*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=23xDn3ReH7E)

Comment: @Jarod42 This is disputed nowaday, because access to the singleton using this idom is slow: at each access the generated assembly code tests if the local static variable is already created. The technic proposed in the Cppcon2016 video in my previous comment is more and more prefered.

Comment: First, thank you for your quick answers !
@Holt I've edited my question, as you can see, TextureManager.o is built without errors.

Comment: Looks like a linkage error, what is the difference in code on files allocation between working version and not working? What are compiler differences?
Older one can handle =default differently.

Comment: "It seems that it can't find the declaration of the constructor which is in TextureManager.cpp".  Pedantic nit:  the *definition* is what it cannot find (which is in TextureManger.cpp).  There is a *declaration* in TextureManager.h.

Comment: @Oliv You have build/main.o twice in the last line. Remove $< in the first rule.

Comment: @Jarod42 Great presentation indeed, but I don't see how my templated class differs from the PIMPL Implementation since it is seems to me roughly the same except for the templated part added to make an "easy to use" tool for upcomming singletons class.

Comment: Works for me, LLVM 7.0. Put Singleton and TextureManager declarations in one .h, =default; definitions to one.cpp, Singleton variable definition to main.cpp.

Comment: @Holt Nice spot! I removed it but now, the undefined teference is to 'main'

Comment: @MartinBonner Sorry, my bad, editing now !

Comment: @AlexeyVoytenko Yes, as I said, I don't think that the problem is the code in itself (since it worked in a project compiled with premake) but I think my problem comes from my poor knowledge of makefiles.

Comment: @Oliv: In your linked presentation, they only hide the `Sinngleton` (or move it as implementation detail). The implementation by itself is identical.

Comment: @Jarod42 No!!! The implementation is not the same, the singleton object has static storage duration, its data are declared at namespace scope, the identity of the singleton object is the namespace where appers its member function. Public member function become free function with external linkage. This is realy realy much more efficient than using the static local trick, because the compiler generate codes that is checked each time you access the variable. With global statics that just do not happen. A translation unit is a singleton object.

Comment: @Oliv: Check might also to be done at TU level (depending **when** compiler instantiate globals of that TU). Threading check for initialization should also be done. Video focuses of interface btw (to hide implementation details), not on performance.

Comment: @Jarod42, When main is called, all static initialization are performed. So this main call is an excellent sequence point. It is much better programming to use this sequence point than checking if initialization has been perform each time the variable is accessed. Using a static local is an anti-pattern.

Comment: @Oliv: Globals of TU doesn't have to be initialized before `main`, but before any usages of any "components" of that TU (which can indeed be done before `main`).

Comment: @Jarod42 It is indeed implementation defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are only using the first dependency in the `$(TARGET)` rule:

```
$(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $(LIBDIR) $< $(LIBS)
#                               ^^
```

My comment was actually wrong because you have a different command between the `@echo` and the actual command:

```
@echo "$(CC) $(CFLAGS) $^ -o $@ $(LIBDIR) $< $(LIBS)"
#                      ^^                 ^^
```

I do not see a point in adding this `echo` line here, I would do as follow:

```
$(TARGET): $(OBJECTS)
    @echo "Linking..."
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $^ -o $@ $(LIBDIR) $(LIBS)
    #               ^^
```

Had you done so, you would have seen your error sooner I think.

Comment: This is it! Thanks a lot. And have a nice day ;)